# C# DotNet Entity Framework Core Migrations Error on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, rider

I'm using JetBrains Rider on Linux. Whenever I run the `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`, it does this in the terminal and gives me this error:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
0104:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Cannot find 'Mono.SystemDependencyProvider, System' dependency
  at Mono.DependencyInjector.get_SystemProvider () [0x0003d] in <a9da539eb2f94b1a84ab84db52450d46>:0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Helper.get_CertificateProvider () [0x00000] in <a9da539eb2f94b1a84ab84db52450d46>:0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Helper.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
 [0x00000] in <a9da539eb2f94b1a84ab84db52450d46>:0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor (System.String fileName, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x0003e] in <a9da539eb2f94
b1a84ab84db52450d46>:0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <a9da539eb2f94b1a84ab84db52450d46>:0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile (System.String filename) [0x00000] in <a9da539eb2f94b1a84ab84db52450d46>:0
  at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetDefaultHostEvidence (System.Reflection.Assembly a) [0x00097] in <a9da539eb2f94b1a84ab84db52450d46>:0
  at System.AppDomain.get_Evidence () [0x00045] in <a9da539eb2f94b1a84ab84db52450d46>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain.get_Evidence()
  at System.AppDomain.CreateDomain (System.String friendlyName, System.Security.Policy.Evidence securityInfo, System.AppDomainSetup info) [0x000de] in <a9da539eb2f94b1a84ab84db52450d46>:0
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.AppDomainOperationExecutor..ctor (System.String assembly, System.String startupAssembly, System.String projectDir, System.String dataDirectory, System.String rootNamespace, System.String lang
uage, System.String[] remainingArguments) [0x0004c] in <27660142d7fa4f02b91c8d5e3bfbdb6d>:0
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor (System.String[] remainingArguments) [0x00042] in <27660142d7fa4f02b91c8d5e3bfbdb6d>:0
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.MigrationsAddCommand.Execute (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <27660142d7fa4f02b91c8d5e3bfbdb6d>:0
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0 (System.String[] args) [0x0003b] in <27660142d7fa4f02b91c8d5e3bfbdb6d>:0
  at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute (System.String[] args) [0x000df] in <27660142d7fa4f02b91c8d5e3bfbdb6d>:0
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0002e] in <27660142d7fa4f02b91c8d5e3bfbdb6d>:0
Cannot find 'Mono.SystemDependencyProvider, System' dependency
```

If anyone knows the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem in the .net 5 web API project

EF tool looks around CreateWebHostBuilder method and returns the error when failed to find it.

```
directories:

/src 
    |-- /YourPorject.Infrastructure
    |-- /YourPorject.API
```

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile(
                    context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + $"/Config/appsettings-dev.json",
                    false, false);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
}
```

Use bash to create and update database

```sh
    cd src/
    dotnet ef migrations add Init 
    --project YourPorject.Infrastructure/YourPorject.Infrastructure.csproj  
    --startup-project YourPorject.API/YourPorject.API.csproj 
    -o ./Repositories/Migrations/

    cd src/
    dotnet ef database update 
    --project YourPorject.Infrastructure/YourPorject.Infrastructure.csproj 
    --startup-project YourPorject.API/YourPorject.API.csproj
```

Use this packages (**It's important**)

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.8" />
</ItemGroup>
```